# ajax page refresh on form submit success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am using this ajax code to submit a form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ticketupdate_message").hide();
$("#ticketupdate_please_wait_box").hide();
$("#ticket_update").submit(function(e){
    $("#ticketupdate_message").hide();
    $("#ticketupdate_please_wait_box").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    dataString=$("#ticket_update").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reviewtickets_history.php?seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>",
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res){
            $("#ticketupdate_please_wait_box").hide();
            $("#ticketupdate_message").html(res);
            $('#ticketupdate_message').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.overlay').fadeOut();
            if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
            {
                window.location.href = res.substr(8);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#ticket_update")[0].reset();
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

how can i add a page refresh if it was successful?

Comment: If you reload the page, what's the point of all the other actions you have in the `success` callback?

Comment: the other actions are not going to be there , i will remove them when i manage to make the page reload

Comment: Refreshing the page will nuke any changes you did to the page inside the success handler...

Answer (score 1):

Use `location.reload();` to reload the page

```
if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
{
    location.reload();
}
```

Refer : [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `location.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

Using `location.reload()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload:

```
     if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
        {
            location.reload();
        }
```

If you want to override cache, add a `true` parameter: `location.reload(true);`

Cheers